# Converting .txt containing two columns ID and GeoJSON Geometry?

Tags: qgis, geojson, geometry

I am working with an unusual format file - it came as a .txt and is separated by tabs.  In the first column is an id number and in the second column is the geometry stores as geoJSON.

When I attempt to import into QGIS as a text layer, breaking it up by tabs and setting the header works.  When I specify the geometry as the geoJSON field I get the error that it is an invalid file.  I am not sure how to approach converting this file into a Shapefile (ideal solution) or something that QGIS can display.

```
Id      geoJSON
49518   {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[29.9596,-2.3272],[29.9189,-2.7028],[29.7235,-2.8189],[29.3706,-2.8401],[29.1497,-2.5917],[29.0405,-2.7447],[28.8619,-2.5309],[29.1194,-2.2488],[29.1361,-1.8602],[29.3616,-1.5092],[29.8237,-1.3089],[29.9149,-1.4825],[30.0524,-1.4314],[30.4704,-1.0525],[30.8394,-1.6514],[30.8567,-2.3151],[30.1356,-2.4382],[29.9596,-2.3272]]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the file using a simple regexp, using sed I found

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)}/\2, "id":\1} /' /tmp/ian.txt
```

gave me:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[29.9596,-2.3272],[29.9189,-2.7028],[29.7235,-2.8189],[29.3706,-2.8401],[29.1497,-2.5917],[29.0405,-2.7447],[28.8619,-2.5309],[29.1194,-2.2488],[29.1361,-1.8602],[29.3616,-1.5092],[29.8237,-1.3089],[29.9149,-1.4825],[30.0524,-1.4314],[30.4704,-1.0525],[30.8394,-1.6514],[30.8567,-2.3151],[30.1356,-2.4382],[29.9596,-2.3272]]], "id":49518}
```

However this fails to [validate as GeoJSON](http://geojsonlint.com/) due to "Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule".

Comment: On the other hand, the current standard https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.6 says `Note: the [GJ2008] specification did not discuss linear ring winding order.  For backwards compatibility, parsers SHOULD NOT reject Polygons that do not follow the right-hand rule.`

Comment: should be fine then

Comment: This helped format the text file - however opening with qgis does not load all features.

I tried adding {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [ to the beginning of the file and ]
} to the end of the file so it would read all of the polygons.   However I think the formatting for geojson formatting is incorrect as it is stored as a single line?